# Existence of a function at base for periodicity

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Given the following evolution IVP/BVP: $\begin{cases} u_t - \Delta u = f &\text{in  }  U \times(0,\infty)\\
> u=0 &\text{on } \partial U \times (0,\infty)\\
> u= g &\text{on } U \times \{t=0\}
> \end{cases}$,
>
> $g\in L^2(U) $, $f \in L^{\infty}(U_T)$ for each $T>0$ and $U_T:= U\times (0,T]$.
>
> Suppose $\tau > 0$ and $f(x,t) = f(x,t+\tau)$ with $x \in U$, for each $t\geq 0$. Prove that there is a $L^2$ function  $g$ whose associated $u$ solving the PDE has the same periodic property as $f$.

Showing uniqueness is pretty straightforward, but I am clueless for existence.

Any hint or suggestion is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: An alternative to Banach's theorem is to use an eigenfunction expansion $u(t,x)=\sum_1^\infty u_n(t)\phi_n(x)$.  The $u_n$'s solve ODEs which are easy to solve, and imposing $\tau-$periodicity allows you to solve for the $g_n$'s in terms of the Fourier coefficients $(f(t,.),\phi_n)$.  Then you just need to show that $G:=\sum g_n\phi_n(x)$ is a well defined sum in $L^2$.

Comment: @user254433 what do you mean by "imposing $\tau$- periodicity allows you to solve for th $g_n$'s in terms of the Fourier coefficients"? What are the $g_n$ in this case? I'm sorry Im a bit confused since for each choice of the base function $g$, we have a (weak) solution for the PDE by 2nd-order parabolic PDE theory. It seems to me that you are assuming something for $u_n$ and then solve for $g_n$?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I'll elaborate more below.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expanded version of my comment:

Let $\{\phi_n\}_1^\infty$ and $\{\lambda_n\}_1^\infty$ be the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ on $U$, and project all functions involved onto the orthonormal basis:

\begin{align}
u_n(t):=(u(t,x),\phi_n(x)),\\
g_n:=(g(x),\phi_n(x)),\\
f_n(t):=(f(t,x),\phi_n(x)).
\end{align}
The $f_n$'s are $\tau$-periodic, and by completeness of the basis, it suffices to consider whether the $u_n$'s are $\tau$-periodic as well.

The $u_n$'s solve the initial value problems
$$
u_n'(t)+\lambda_n u_n(t)=f_n(t),\\
u_n(0)=g_n,
$$
which have the solutions
$$
u_n(t)=e^{-\lambda_n t}g_n+\int_0^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}f_n(s)ds.
$$
We have $\tau$-periodicity if and only if $u_n(t+\tau)=u_n(t)$.  Substituting the solution into this expression, extending $f_n$ to $\mathbb R$ using periodicity, and changing variables $s\to s+\tau$ in the integral yields the equation
$$
e^{-\lambda_n(t+\tau)}g_n+\int_{-\tau}^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}f_n(s)ds=e^{-\lambda_nt}g_n+\int_{0}^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}f_n(s)ds,
$$
which reduces to
\begin{align}
(e^{-\lambda_n\tau}-1)g_n&=-\int_{-\tau}^0e^{\lambda_ns}f_n(s)ds\\
&=-e^{-\lambda_n \tau}\int_0^\tau e^{\lambda_n s}f_n(s)ds.
\end{align}
Since $\lambda_n>0$ for all $n$, we conclude that
$$
g_n=\frac{1}{e^{\lambda_n\tau}-1}\int_0^\tau e^{\lambda_n s}f_n(s)ds.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand your approach now. One more thing, so for each $x \in U$, we look at the orthonormal basis provided above (the $u_n(t)$, $f_n(t)$ ,...). They become the basis for that particular point in $U$, which are functions from $(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. After those calculations involving integrating vector-valued functions, we obtain, for each $n$ and the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda _ n$, the coefficient $g_n$ to be a function depending on $x$. Is this correct? The last step is to show $G$ converges on $U$. Is this correct?

Comment: How do we even show convergence for that? I can deduce that $|g_n| \leq  \frac {||f_n||_{L^{\infty}}}{\lambda _n}$, but then it's not so clear that the series converges let alone well-definedness in $L^2$.

Comment: @S_j The orthonormal basis is the $\phi_n$'s, and $(u(t,x),\phi_n(x))$ denotes $\int_U u(t,x)\phi_n(x)dx$ (the inner product on $L^2$).  The $g_n$'s are thus constants, and the $u_n(t)$'s are maps $(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$.

I have to think about convergence.  If $f\in C^\infty$, then integrating the $g_n$ integral by parts gives series convergence (noting that $\lambda_n\sim n^{2/d}$ by Weyl's Law).  Maybe after that approximation can be used to deduce the result for $f\in L^2$.

Comment: @S_j Sorry I removed my edits since they didn't work.  A tricky problem!

Comment: No worries I was gonna mention something wasn't quite right.

Comment: $\lambda_{n} \sim n^{\frac{2}{d}}$ doesn't give convergence since $d>n$.